# Why does the definition of Cow use "as" in Owned(<B as ToOwned>::Owned)?

Tags: rust

Here's how [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) is defined:

```
pub enum Cow<'a, B>
where
    B: 'a + ToOwned + ?Sized,
{
    Borrowed(&'a B),
    Owned(<B as ToOwned>::Owned),
}
```

Why is `B as ToOwned` there? In order to remove `'a` and `?Sized` bounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just being explicit via [fully qualified syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name). It could equally have been defined as

```
pub enum Cow<'a, B>
where
    B: 'a + ToOwned + ?Sized,
{
    Borrowed(&'a B),
    Owned(B::Owned),
}
```

This syntax is how you access the *associated type* of `B`'s implementation of `ToOwned`.